# Match height of Nested table with parent table having cell with wrapped text

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop, altova

I have a requirement in xsl-fo, where i am nesting a table in a parent table.Now when i populate the table cell in the parent table and the content does not wrap, it's fine (i.e, the height of the nested table row is same as parent table row). But when the content in the table cell of the parent table wraps to the next line.There is a height mismatch between nested table cell and parent table cell. Is there any way to rectify this, in lines of nested table inheriting characteristics of parent table.